# How to set Parallelism to Storm Topology which store data into child-parent relationship table?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm using a `Apache Storm` to collect some real time data from `Twitter Api's`. I have written a `Storm Topology` with a `kafka-spout` and 10 `bolts`. I'm trying to store the data into `Postgres` tables with child-parent relationship.

My problem:

0) As we know `Storm` works on parallelism all the data is inserted at once to all the tables where only few tables are getting the data.

1) i kept default count 1 parallelism to all my `bolts`.To insert data into all tables i kept 2 sec sleep method in each execute method of `bolts`.where all the data is entering into storm but it's taking long time to insert data into tables and getting Fatal error and next bolt is recovering itself.

I need solution for:
How do i set parallelism count to my `storm bolts` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you put sleep in your execute methods... It is obvious that you waste a lot of resources and your topology throughput is tiny... About your question: setting the correct parallelism is very hard. It depends on your expected data rate, hardware, spout/bolt implementations etc... What is your concrete problem?

Comment: i have tables with parent and child relationships .i.e., after insertion of one table only other tables have to insert.we wrote bolts for all tables and all bolts are executing parallely so that child tables are not able to insert the data because of parent relationship.so i used the sleep method in the execute method. is there is any alternative for my issue. @ Matthias J. Sax

Comment: I would not work with sleep, as this slows your topology down... For you child insert bolt, I would recommend to first query the parent table before inserting -- only delay the child insert if the parent got not inserted yet.

Comment: yeah ! i'm also doing the same :) i kept sleep in the child blots only.I just wanted to know is their any other way or not @Matthias J. Sax

Comment: I don't see a different way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060353/while-exectuing-my-topology-postgres-is-establishing-11-connections-for-each-bol please answer the following question @Matthias J. Sax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079414/how-to-excute-one-bolt-after-the-other-when-each-bolt-takes-data-from-same-spout @Matthias J. Sax  this may give you clear idea of keeping sleep in bolts